# Value stored to 'image' during its initialization is never read

Tags: memory-leaks, memory-management

When running the analyze in xcode 4.2 i have the warning "Value stored to 'image' during its initialization is never read." Anyone can help me out what is wrong with the code?

```
UIImage *image=[[[UIImage alloc] init]autorelease];
if (carousel==recipeCarousel) {
    image = [recipeItems objectAtIndex:index];
} else {
    image = [packItems objectAtIndex:index];
}    
UIView *view = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];
return view;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have alloc the UIImage with this code

```
UIImage *image=[[[UIImage alloc] init]autorelease];
```

but later you assign object in `recipeItems` or `packItems`

so that you will lose your control to the allocated object.

So you can either do this

```
UIImage *image = nil;

if (carousel==recipeCarousel) {
    image = [recipeItems objectAtIndex:index];
} else {
    image = [packItems objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

or

```
NSArray *targetItems = nil;

if (carousel==recipeCarousel) {
    targetItems = recipeItems;
} else {
    targetItems = packItems;
}    

UIImage *image = [targetItems objectAtIndex:index];
```